# Why does the php-code kind of overwrite the javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

My first stumbling steps with JS **AND** PHP.

I was trying around and found, that apparently JS doesn't seem to make persistent changes in the HTML anymore when JS and PHP refer to the same element. When clicking the button in my example the background color changes for a part of a second and then just goes back to the old status. Obviously the PHP code has somthing to do with it. I wonder WHY exactly this happens and HOW to deal with it (Given I would really want the background color to change when pressing the button AND execute the PHP code also).

HTML/PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>Rechner</title>
<link href="neu/rezepte.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<h2>Ein simpler Taschenrechner.</h2>

<form action = "rezepte.php" method = "post">

<p>Zahl1: </p><input type="text" name="a" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST["a"])&&is_numeric($_POST["a"])) {echo $_POST["a"];}?>"><br/>

<p>Wähle eine Rechenoperation:</p>
<select name="rz">
<option>+</option>    
<option>-</option>    
<option>*</option>    
<option>/</option>    
</select><br/>
 <p>Zahl2: </p><input type="text" name="b" value ="<?php if(isset($_POST["b"])&&is_numeric($_POST["b"])) {echo $_POST["b"];}?>"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Rechne!" id="test">

</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST["a"])&& is_numeric($_POST["a"]) && isset($_POST["b"])&& is_numeric($_POST["b"])) {
    switch($_POST["rz"]) {
        case "+": 
            $c = $_POST["a"] + $_POST["b"]; 
            break;
        case "-": 
            $c = $_POST["a"] - $_POST["b"]; 
            break;
        case "*": 
            $c = $_POST["a"] * $_POST["b"]; 
            break;
        case "/": 
            $c = $_POST["a"] / $_POST["b"]; 
            break;
    }
    echo "<h3>Das Ergebnis lautet $c. </h3>";
}

?>
<script src='php_js.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
function init() {
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", style);
}

function style() {
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.add("yellow");
}

window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

Comment: Er, could you show us the PHP code?

Comment: I don't see what PHP has to do with this. And unless you save the changes somewhere, the web is stateless.

Comment: The input type of submit submits the form, and the page is reloaded as the server response. Changes made by JS are persistent only for the lifetime of the document.

Comment: I guess you're just submitting the form and the page reloads.

Comment: The page reloads. If you want to call a PHP and not lose all changes to the page done with script, you need to AJAX the rezepte.php - I assume you are just playing around since a php calculator is plain silly :) - you COULD persist the change to the style by sending the click to the PHP too and change the class in the PHP

Comment: Once you click the button, the css class `yellow` is added to the `body` tag but then the page reloads and is parsed from the source file. Since the source file has no `yellow` class added to the `body` tag, the background stays white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to understand that PHP runs server side, javascript runs client side. This means your HTML page will be prepared server side, all the PHP will run there and produce your HTML or do any work. Then only javascript and HTML will hit your browser. As others have also said your page will also refresh after submitting the form. so for that split second before the page refresh the click event will fire and add the yellow class, then the whole page will refresh, add the click event listener again, but page state will be before the click since the page has just refreshed and the yellow class wont have been added yet.

Heres a bunch of information on how to avoid that: http://www.codexpedia.com/javascript/submitting-html-form-without-reload-the-page/

Answer (score 1):

This really has nothing to do with php.

What's happening is that your `style` function runs, but then the default event for the submit button (that is "actually submit the form") takes over and your form is sent, causing a page reload. You only see the style change for a split second while the submit is being done and, since a web page does not maintain state between page loads, the style change is reverted as soon as the page loads again.